# Error- ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, blob, clob

I am attempting to read a `BLOB` message and display it as a variable in one of my procedures, but am getting the error below:

> Error - ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW
> conversion (actual: 9923, maximum: 2000)

I have googled and found a suggestion to trim the `BLOB` message as below, but I would rather display the complete `BLOB` message as a string.

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(dbms_lob.substr(variable_name,2000,1))
```

How can I display the complete message? Is there a setting on either the database or procedure level that I can change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this worked by using the option described in

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_varchar_datatype.htm

Comment: Could you explain how to insert it?

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the buffer issue by reading the `BLOB` value in chunks. In order to do that, you can define a user defined function (UDF) [as suggested here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_varchar_datatype.htm). The following UDF reads the `BLOB` field one chunk at a time, converts that to `VARCHAR2` and appends the results consecutively to return the result as a `CLOB`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VC2CLOB_FROM_BLOB(B BLOB)
RETURN CLOB IS
    c CLOB;
    n NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF (b IS NULL) THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    IF (LENGTH(b) = 0) THEN
        RETURN EMPTY_CLOB();
    END IF;
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(c, TRUE);
    n := 1;
    WHILE (n + 32767 <= LENGTH(b)) LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(c, 32767, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b, 32767, n)));
        n := n + 32767;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(c, LENGTH(b) - n + 1, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b, LENGTH(b) - n + 1, n)));
    RETURN c;
END;
/
```

After having defined it, you can simply call it like so:

```
SELECT VC2CLOB_FROM_BLOB(variable_name);
```

Worked like a charm for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(), instead of trimming the string